# Web-App access to different APIs (Best Practices)

Tags: node.js, rest, api, http

So I want to create a web-app with NodeJS which accesses three different APIs:

- My Own RESTful-API connected to a database
- Third party API #1
- Third party API #2

Should I really implement access to all three APIs in my web-app or should I expand my own API to work as an interface to the other two APIs?

I know this question may be very subjective but I didn't find anything about this situation on the web. I hope someone can give me some information how to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An api gatweway sound like a good solution for you.

In general - Your client app will communicate only with the gateway, and the gateway it self will redirect the request into your relevant web app.

I recommend you to read this article about API Gateways: https://blog.risingstack.com/building-an-api-gateway-using-nodejs/

Comment: Thank you very much. For the advice and for the article. I just didn't know what I am searching for. But the term API Gateway helps a lot.